# I need to know which service has executed a script, to powershell

Tags: powershell, service, process, startup, running-count

I need to know which service has executed a script from the same script.

For example The service service_Test executed the test script. From the test script I want to know which service has executed it.

I have not found a way to do this, I can only see which services are running.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're asking is how to **determine the path of the executable that launched the current PowerShell process**, so you can compare it to your service executable path.

You can do this with a combination of [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) and [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) with the [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) WMI class, using the [automatic `$PID` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pid) to get the current process' ID:

```bash
$parentExecutablePath = 
  (Get-Process -Id `
    (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID").ParentProcessId
  ).Path
```

---

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the solution can be simplified, given that PowerShell now decorates the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances output by `Get-Process` with a `.Parent` property:

```bash
# PS v7+ - also works on Unix-like platforms.
$parentExecutablePath =
  (Get-Process -Id $PID).Parent.Path
```

Not only is this simpler and shorter, it also works on *Unix*-like platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved with>

```
$service_cmd = get-Process -id $PID |select -expand name
write-output $service_cmd
$service_pid = $PID
write-output $service_pid
$contp = 1

while (($service_cmd -ne "dsmcsvc") -and ($contp -le 5)){
    $service_pid = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $service_pid").ParentProcessId
    write-output $service_pid
    $service_cmd = get-Process -id $service_pid |select -expand name
    $contp += 1
}
$service_name = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId=$service_pid").Name
```

Regards